# How to remove every Nth element from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would I remove every third element from the array below, starting with the third element, so that the end result will look like this, **without creating a new array**?

> This is the song that never ends, yes it goes on and on my friends. Some people started singing it, not knowing what it was and they will continue singing it forever just because

In theory, I am thinking of using pop instead of slice() since slice creates a new array. How would I go about solving this?

```js
var thisArray = [ 'T','h','a','i','s','b',' ','i','c','s',' ','a','t','h','e','e',' ','t','s','o','r','n','g','t',' ','t','n','h','a','s','t',' ','o','n','e','o','v','e','a','r',' ','f','e','n','a','d','s','p',',',' ','p','y','e','i','s',' ','p','i','t','o',' ','g',' ','o','e','i','s',' ','t','o','n','e',' ','a',' ','n','d',' ',' ','o','i','n',' ','a','m','y',' ',' ','f','a','r','i',' ','e','n','o','d','s','i',' ','S',' ','o','m','a','e',' ','a','p','e',' ','o','p','a','l','e','r',' ','s',' ','t','a','a','r','t',' ','e','d','u',' ','s',' ','i','n','g','g','i',' ','n','g','o',' ','i','t','t',',',' ',' ','n','i','o','t','h',' ','k','a','n','o',' ','w','i',' ','n','g','o',' ','w','r','h','a','i','t',' ','s','i','t','h',' ','w','r','a','s','h',' ','A',' ','n','d','a',' ','t','o','h','e',' ','y',' ','a','w','i','p','l','l','o',' ','c','r','o','n',' ','t','i','p','n','u','i','e',' ','t','s','i',' ','n','g',' ','i','n',' ','g',' ','s','i','t','h',' ','f','r','o','r',' ','e','v','t','e','r','t',' ','j','u','u','s','t','t',' ','a','b','e','l','c','a',' ','u','s','l','e'];

for(var i=2; i<thisArray.length; i++){
     thisArray.pop()
     document.write (thisArray);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to remove an element from the array. Where the first argument is defined as the index and second as the number elements to be deleted.

To remove elements at 3rd position use a while loop which iterates in backward and then delete the element based on the position.

```js
var thisArray = ['T', 'h', 'a', 'i', 's', 'b', ' ', 'i', 'c', 's', ' ', 'a', 't', 'h', 'e', 'e', ' ', 't', 's', 'o', 'r', 'n', 'g', 't', ' ', 't', 'n', 'h', 'a', 's', 't', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'f', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'd', 's', 'p', ',', ' ', 'p', 'y', 'e', 'i', 's', ' ', 'p', 'i', 't', 'o', ' ', 'g', ' ', 'o', 'e', 'i', 's', ' ', 't', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'n', 'd', ' ', ' ', 'o', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'a', 'm', 'y', ' ', ' ', 'f', 'a', 'r', 'i', ' ', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'd', 's', 'i', ' ', 'S', ' ', 'o', 'm', 'a', 'e', ' ', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'o', 'p', 'a', 'l', 'e', 'r', ' ', 's', ' ', 't', 'a', 'a', 'r', 't', ' ', 'e', 'd', 'u', ' ', 's', ' ', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'g', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', 'o', ' ', 'i', 't', 't', ',', ' ', ' ', 'n', 'i', 'o', 't', 'h', ' ', 'k', 'a', 'n', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'h', 'a', 'i', 't', ' ', 's', 'i', 't', 'h', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'a', 's', 'h', ' ', 'A', ' ', 'n', 'd', 'a', ' ', 't', 'o', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'y', ' ', 'a', 'w', 'i', 'p', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'c', 'r', 'o', 'n', ' ', 't', 'i', 'p', 'n', 'u', 'i', 'e', ' ', 't', 's', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'g', ' ', 's', 'i', 't', 'h', ' ', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'e', 'v', 't', 'e', 'r', 't', ' ', 'j', 'u', 'u', 's', 't', 't', ' ', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'l', 'c', 'a', ' ', 'u', 's', 'l', 'e'];
var i = thisArray.length;

while (i--) {
  (i + 1) % 3 === 0 && thisArray.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(thisArray);
```

---

Or a better way would be simply iterating over elements in third position instead of iterating over each element.

```js
var thisArray = ['T', 'h', 'a', 'i', 's', 'b', ' ', 'i', 'c', 's', ' ', 'a', 't', 'h', 'e', 'e', ' ', 't', 's', 'o', 'r', 'n', 'g', 't', ' ', 't', 'n', 'h', 'a', 's', 't', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'f', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'd', 's', 'p', ',', ' ', 'p', 'y', 'e', 'i', 's', ' ', 'p', 'i', 't', 'o', ' ', 'g', ' ', 'o', 'e', 'i', 's', ' ', 't', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'n', 'd', ' ', ' ', 'o', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'a', 'm', 'y', ' ', ' ', 'f', 'a', 'r', 'i', ' ', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'd', 's', 'i', ' ', 'S', ' ', 'o', 'm', 'a', 'e', ' ', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'o', 'p', 'a', 'l', 'e', 'r', ' ', 's', ' ', 't', 'a', 'a', 'r', 't', ' ', 'e', 'd', 'u', ' ', 's', ' ', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'g', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', 'o', ' ', 'i', 't', 't', ',', ' ', ' ', 'n', 'i', 'o', 't', 'h', ' ', 'k', 'a', 'n', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'h', 'a', 'i', 't', ' ', 's', 'i', 't', 'h', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'a', 's', 'h', ' ', 'A', ' ', 'n', 'd', 'a', ' ', 't', 'o', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'y', ' ', 'a', 'w', 'i', 'p', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'c', 'r', 'o', 'n', ' ', 't', 'i', 'p', 'n', 'u', 'i', 'e', ' ', 't', 's', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'g', ' ', 's', 'i', 't', 'h', ' ', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'e', 'v', 't', 'e', 'r', 't', ' ', 'j', 'u', 'u', 's', 't', 't', ' ', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'l', 'c', 'a', ' ', 'u', 's', 'l', 'e'];
var i = Math.floor(thisArray.length / 3);

while (i--) {
  thisArray.splice((i + 1) * 3 - 1, 1);
}

console.log(thisArray);
```

---

Or you can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method and filter based on the index of the element. Which generates a new array so update the variable with the returned array.

```js
var thisArray = ['T', 'h', 'a', 'i', 's', 'b', ' ', 'i', 'c', 's', ' ', 'a', 't', 'h', 'e', 'e', ' ', 't', 's', 'o', 'r', 'n', 'g', 't', ' ', 't', 'n', 'h', 'a', 's', 't', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'f', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'd', 's', 'p', ',', ' ', 'p', 'y', 'e', 'i', 's', ' ', 'p', 'i', 't', 'o', ' ', 'g', ' ', 'o', 'e', 'i', 's', ' ', 't', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'n', 'd', ' ', ' ', 'o', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'a', 'm', 'y', ' ', ' ', 'f', 'a', 'r', 'i', ' ', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'd', 's', 'i', ' ', 'S', ' ', 'o', 'm', 'a', 'e', ' ', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'o', 'p', 'a', 'l', 'e', 'r', ' ', 's', ' ', 't', 'a', 'a', 'r', 't', ' ', 'e', 'd', 'u', ' ', 's', ' ', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'g', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', 'o', ' ', 'i', 't', 't', ',', ' ', ' ', 'n', 'i', 'o', 't', 'h', ' ', 'k', 'a', 'n', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'h', 'a', 'i', 't', ' ', 's', 'i', 't', 'h', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'a', 's', 'h', ' ', 'A', ' ', 'n', 'd', 'a', ' ', 't', 'o', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'y', ' ', 'a', 'w', 'i', 'p', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'c', 'r', 'o', 'n', ' ', 't', 'i', 'p', 'n', 'u', 'i', 'e', ' ', 't', 's', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'g', ' ', 's', 'i', 't', 'h', ' ', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'e', 'v', 't', 'e', 'r', 't', ' ', 'j', 'u', 'u', 's', 't', 't', ' ', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'l', 'c', 'a', ' ', 'u', 's', 'l', 'e'];

thisArray = thisArray.filter(function(_, i) {
  return (i + 1) % 3;
})

console.log(thisArray);
```

Comment: +1 to filtering by index. I wanted to filter custom days of the week based on bits, so I used `arr.filter((_,i) => Math.pow(2, i) & daysToInclude)` so eg `62` is "weekends off"

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the array from the end and calculate the position for splicing.

```js
var data = [ 'T','h','a','i','s','b',' ','i','c','s',' ','a','t','h','e','e',' ','t','s','o','r','n','g','t',' ','t','n','h','a','s','t',' ','o','n','e','o','v','e','a','r',' ','f','e','n','a','d','s','p',',',' ','p','y','e','i','s',' ','p','i','t','o',' ','g',' ','o','e','i','s',' ','t','o','n','e',' ','a',' ','n','d',' ',' ','o','i','n',' ','a','m','y',' ',' ','f','a','r','i',' ','e','n','o','d','s','i',' ','S',' ','o','m','a','e',' ','a','p','e',' ','o','p','a','l','e','r',' ','s',' ','t','a','a','r','t',' ','e','d','u',' ','s',' ','i','n','g','g','i',' ','n','g','o',' ','i','t','t',',',' ',' ','n','i','o','t','h',' ','k','a','n','o',' ','w','i',' ','n','g','o',' ','w','r','h','a','i','t',' ','s','i','t','h',' ','w','r','a','s','h',' ','A',' ','n','d','a',' ','t','o','h','e',' ','y',' ','a','w','i','p','l','l','o',' ','c','r','o','n',' ','t','i','p','n','u','i','e',' ','t','s','i',' ','n','g',' ','i','n',' ','g',' ','s','i','t','h',' ','f','r','o','r',' ','e','v','t','e','r','t',' ','j','u','u','s','t','t',' ','a','b','e','l','c','a',' ','u','s','l','e'],
    n = 3,
    i = Math.floor(data.length / n);
    
while (i--) {
    data.splice((i + 1) * n - 1, 1);
}
console.log(data.join(''));
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Sorry, misread the post, didn't realize you wanted to do this without making a new array. This method works if you are willing to make a new array.

You could use the array filter function to remove every third element...

```
var thisArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];

thisArray = thisArray.filter(function(value, index) {
  return (index + 1) % 3 != 0;
});
```

The output of this would be: `['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']`.

Comment: minor improvement since evaluating a falsey zero is also false:

`thisArray.filter((v,i) => i % 3)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var thisArray = [ 'T','h','a','i','s','b',' ','i','c','s',' ','a','t','h','e','e',' ','t','s','o','r','n','g','t',' ','t','n','h','a','s','t',' ','o','n','e','o','v','e','a','r',' ','f','e','n','a','d','s','p',',',' ','p','y','e','i','s',' ','p','i','t','o',' ','g',' ','o','e','i','s',' ','t','o','n','e',' ','a',' ','n','d',' ',' ','o','i','n',' ','a','m','y',' ',' ','f','a','r','i',' ','e','n','o','d','s','i',' ','S',' ','o','m','a','e',' ','a','p','e',' ','o','p','a','l','e','r',' ','s',' ','t','a','a','r','t',' ','e','d','u',' ','s',' ','i','n','g','g','i',' ','n','g','o',' ','i','t','t',',',' ',' ','n','i','o','t','h',' ','k','a','n','o',' ','w','i',' ','n','g','o',' ','w','r','h','a','i','t',' ','s','i','t','h',' ','w','r','a','s','h',' ','A',' ','n','d','a',' ','t','o','h','e',' ','y',' ','a','w','i','p','l','l','o',' ','c','r','o','n',' ','t','i','p','n','u','i','e',' ','t','s','i',' ','n','g',' ','i','n',' ','g',' ','s','i','t','h',' ','f','r','o','r',' ','e','v','t','e','r','t',' ','j','u','u','s','t','t',' ','a','b','e','l','c','a',' ','u','s','l','e'];

var i = 3; var j=1; var l=thisArray.length;
while(i-j<l) {
   thisArray.splice(i-j,1);
   i=i+3;
   j++;
   l=thisArray.length;
}

console.log(thisArray.join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in-place, without worrying about `splice`.

```js
var thisArray = [ 'T','h','a','i','s','b',' ','i','c','s',' ','a','t','h','e','e',' ','t','s','o','r','n','g','t',' ','t','n','h','a','s','t',' ','o','n','e','o','v','e','a','r',' ','f','e','n','a','d','s','p',',',' ','p','y','e','i','s',' ','p','i','t','o',' ','g',' ','o','e','i','s',' ','t','o','n','e',' ','a',' ','n','d',' ',' ','o','i','n',' ','a','m','y',' ',' ','f','a','r','i',' ','e','n','o','d','s','i',' ','S',' ','o','m','a','e',' ','a','p','e',' ','o','p','a','l','e','r',' ','s',' ','t','a','a','r','t',' ','e','d','u',' ','s',' ','i','n','g','g','i',' ','n','g','o',' ','i','t','t',',',' ',' ','n','i','o','t','h',' ','k','a','n','o',' ','w','i',' ','n','g','o',' ','w','r','h','a','i','t',' ','s','i','t','h',' ','w','r','a','s','h',' ','A',' ','n','d','a',' ','t','o','h','e',' ','y',' ','a','w','i','p','l','l','o',' ','c','r','o','n',' ','t','i','p','n','u','i','e',' ','t','s','i',' ','n','g',' ','i','n',' ','g',' ','s','i','t','h',' ','f','r','o','r',' ','e','v','t','e','r','t',' ','j','u','u','s','t','t',' ','a','b','e','l','c','a',' ','u','s','l','e'];

function removeEvery(array, n) {
  let j = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) % n) array[j++] = array[i];
  }
  array.length = j;

  return array;
}

console.log(removeEvery(thisArray, 3).join(''));
```

Here is a simple recursive solution:

```
function removeEvery([one, two, three, ...rest]) {
  return one === undefined ? [] : [one, two, ...rest];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `while` loop to `splice` the elements.

```js
var arr = ['T', 'h', 'a', 'i', 's', 'b', ' ', 'i', 'c', 's', ' ', 'a', 't', 'h', 'e', 'e', ' ', 't', 's', 'o', 'r', 'n', 'g', 't', ' ', 't', 'n', 'h', 'a', 's', 't', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'f', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'd', 's', 'p', ',', ' ', 'p', 'y', 'e', 'i', 's', ' ', 'p', 'i', 't', 'o', ' ', 'g', ' ', 'o', 'e', 'i', 's', ' ', 't', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'n', 'd', ' ', ' ', 'o', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'a', 'm', 'y', ' ', ' ', 'f', 'a', 'r', 'i', ' ', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'd', 's', 'i', ' ', 'S', ' ', 'o', 'm', 'a', 'e', ' ', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'o', 'p', 'a', 'l', 'e', 'r', ' ', 's', ' ', 't', 'a', 'a', 'r', 't', ' ', 'e', 'd', 'u', ' ', 's', ' ', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'g', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', 'o', ' ', 'i', 't', 't', ',', ' ', ' ', 'n', 'i', 'o', 't', 'h', ' ', 'k', 'a', 'n', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'h', 'a', 'i', 't', ' ', 's', 'i', 't', 'h', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'a', 's', 'h', ' ', 'A', ' ', 'n', 'd', 'a', ' ', 't', 'o', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'y', ' ', 'a', 'w', 'i', 'p', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'c', 'r', 'o', 'n', ' ', 't', 'i', 'p', 'n', 'u', 'i', 'e', ' ', 't', 's', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'g', ' ', 's', 'i', 't', 'h', ' ', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'e', 'v', 't', 'e', 'r', 't', ' ', 'j', 'u', 'u', 's', 't', 't', ' ', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'l', 'c', 'a', ' ', 'u', 's', 'l', 'e'];

function remove3rd(arr) {

  let cut = 2;
  while (cut < arr.length) {
    arr.splice(cut, 1);
    cut += 2;
  }
 
  return arr;

}

console.log(remove3rd(arr));
```

Or you could use recursion and `splice` :

```js
var arr = ['T', 'h', 'a', 'i', 's', 'b', ' ', 'i', 'c', 's', ' ', 'a', 't', 'h', 'e', 'e', ' ', 't', 's', 'o', 'r', 'n', 'g', 't', ' ', 't', 'n', 'h', 'a', 's', 't', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'f', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'd', 's', 'p', ',', ' ', 'p', 'y', 'e', 'i', 's', ' ', 'p', 'i', 't', 'o', ' ', 'g', ' ', 'o', 'e', 'i', 's', ' ', 't', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'n', 'd', ' ', ' ', 'o', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'a', 'm', 'y', ' ', ' ', 'f', 'a', 'r', 'i', ' ', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'd', 's', 'i', ' ', 'S', ' ', 'o', 'm', 'a', 'e', ' ', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'o', 'p', 'a', 'l', 'e', 'r', ' ', 's', ' ', 't', 'a', 'a', 'r', 't', ' ', 'e', 'd', 'u', ' ', 's', ' ', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'g', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', 'o', ' ', 'i', 't', 't', ',', ' ', ' ', 'n', 'i', 'o', 't', 'h', ' ', 'k', 'a', 'n', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'h', 'a', 'i', 't', ' ', 's', 'i', 't', 'h', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'a', 's', 'h', ' ', 'A', ' ', 'n', 'd', 'a', ' ', 't', 'o', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'y', ' ', 'a', 'w', 'i', 'p', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'c', 'r', 'o', 'n', ' ', 't', 'i', 'p', 'n', 'u', 'i', 'e', ' ', 't', 's', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'g', ' ', 's', 'i', 't', 'h', ' ', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'e', 'v', 't', 'e', 'r', 't', ' ', 'j', 'u', 'u', 's', 't', 't', ' ', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'l', 'c', 'a', ' ', 'u', 's', 'l', 'e'];

function remove3rd(arr, cut) {

  if (cut > arr.length) return arr;

  arr.splice(cut, 1);

  return remove3rd(arr, cut + 2);

}

console.log(remove3rd(arr, 2));
```

and with `reduce` for the fun of it

```js
var arr = ['T', 'h', 'a', 'i', 's', 'b', ' ', 'i', 'c', 's', ' ', 'a', 't', 'h', 'e', 'e', ' ', 't', 's', 'o', 'r', 'n', 'g', 't', ' ', 't', 'n', 'h', 'a', 's', 't', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'f', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'd', 's', 'p', ',', ' ', 'p', 'y', 'e', 'i', 's', ' ', 'p', 'i', 't', 'o', ' ', 'g', ' ', 'o', 'e', 'i', 's', ' ', 't', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'n', 'd', ' ', ' ', 'o', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'a', 'm', 'y', ' ', ' ', 'f', 'a', 'r', 'i', ' ', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'd', 's', 'i', ' ', 'S', ' ', 'o', 'm', 'a', 'e', ' ', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'o', 'p', 'a', 'l', 'e', 'r', ' ', 's', ' ', 't', 'a', 'a', 'r', 't', ' ', 'e', 'd', 'u', ' ', 's', ' ', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'g', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', 'o', ' ', 'i', 't', 't', ',', ' ', ' ', 'n', 'i', 'o', 't', 'h', ' ', 'k', 'a', 'n', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'h', 'a', 'i', 't', ' ', 's', 'i', 't', 'h', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'a', 's', 'h', ' ', 'A', ' ', 'n', 'd', 'a', ' ', 't', 'o', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'y', ' ', 'a', 'w', 'i', 'p', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'c', 'r', 'o', 'n', ' ', 't', 'i', 'p', 'n', 'u', 'i', 'e', ' ', 't', 's', 'i', ' ', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'g', ' ', 's', 'i', 't', 'h', ' ', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'e', 'v', 't', 'e', 'r', 't', ' ', 'j', 'u', 'u', 's', 't', 't', ' ', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'l', 'c', 'a', ' ', 'u', 's', 'l', 'e'];

arr.reduce((_, val, ind) => ind % 2 == 0 ? arr.splice(ind, 1) : arr);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function dropRightelement(arr, num=1) {
    if(arr.length <= num) {
        return [];
    }else {
      let newarr = arr.slice(0, arr.length - num);
      return newarr;  
    }
}
console.log(dropRightelement([], 2))
```